# How to change Background of my Navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, typescript, ionic-framework, tabs

I use ionic 3.
How to put a image in the background of my Navigation bar?

```html
<ion-tabs color="dark">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Sp" tabIcon="ios"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Vs" tabIcon="ios"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Im" tabIcon="ios"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Alm" tabIcon="ios"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabTitle="Sts" tabIcon="ios"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try adding below working code in your screen

```
<ion-header class="commonHeaderCls">
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title></ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

add below code in your css
.commonHeaderCls .toolbar-background {
      height: 100%;
      background: url(../assets/imgs/header_logo.png);
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: auto 100%;
      z-index: 5000;
}

[Please note that you have to use your own image path instead of header_logo.png]

Comment: Thank you, it only works on the top navbar (the bottom navigation bar didn't change). On the navigation bar top, I had a button and a logo they both disappeared what should I do?

Comment: Please use <ion-footer> instead and it will be great if you share your code and screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with CSS:

```
ions-tabs {
    background: url(http://background/here.jpg) repeat-x center center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: The code is not clear, it shows me errors.
And where should I put that?

Comment: i try this but my background is still black.

Answer (score 0):

add this in ur css file

```
ions-tabs {
    background:url(image.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:center center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: In order to change the background color.You should change ur css first. Go to ur css file and make background-color:transparent. after that you can see the image

Comment: No, I want to integrate a background image.

Comment: I put the color transparent, in app.scc page, in tabs.html, but no change..  the navigation bar becomes white only.. I don't understand.

Comment: not color i said to you change the background color

Comment: because when you put the background image than any div that is upper on background image shows her background color..so make background color transparent of every div that have background color if you want to show the image.

Comment: I'm confused, can you show me directly what I need to do?

Comment: send me your css and code on my email.mtahseen1122@gmail.com

Comment: .ts file can be send via gmail

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding below code

```
<ion-tabs color="dark" class="custom-tabs">
   <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Sp" tabIcon="ios"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Vs" tabIcon="ios"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Im" tabIcon="ios"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Alm" tabIcon="ios"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabTitle="Sts" tabIcon="ios"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

and add below code in your css

```
.custom-tabs{
   .tabbar{
      background: url(../assets/imgs/header_logo.png);
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: auto 100%;
   }
 }
```

[Please note that you have to use your own image path instead of header_logo.png]